# How to fetch more than 4 results google json feed load api?

Tags: android, rss, google-feed-api

Currently when I call google rss/atom feed loader, I always get only 4 results in the response.
How can I get all the items in the response?

I need the results for my android app.

'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml'

Comment: I got the answer. I just need to add a "num" parameter to my query.

Comment: answer your own question and accept it, if you got answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. I just need to add a "num" parameter to my query
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml&num=30

Answer (score 1):

The 'num' parameter does not work for 'find' method it only works for 'load' method. So I don't think there is any solution to this problem.

Comment: You are right. I previously gave the url for find method. Updated the question and answer with load method urls.

Answer (score 0):

Use `feed.setNumEntries(7);` for retrieving more than 4 entries or number of items you want to retrieve.

```
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.wsj.com/xml/rss/3_7085.xml");
feed.setNumEntries(7);
```

Read more: [Google Feed API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide)